# Android package name starting with .net instead oft .com to keep app in play store?

Tags: java, android, package, android-package-managers

Can I use the android package name as `net.myDomainName.myApplicationName` instead of
`com.myDomainName.myApplicationName`  to keep my app in Google play store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
According to [convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) about the package name it should be company domain written backwards, so it will be unique.
domainname.net is 100% valid.